# XML - XSLT - Using two XML files - Additions to XML file consulting another XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have the following problem that, for me, is kind of tricky,

Basically I need to be able to modify a XML input file with data that I have stored in another XML file, so I would have to use 2 input XML files,

I have the following XML file, which is the one I want to modify (basically, just make additions to it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <text-prop name="displayName">PersonTemplate</text-prop>
    <setup>
        <simple-master-page name="MasterPage" id="2">
            <footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <prop name="contentType">html</prop>
                    <text-prop name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-prop>
                </text>
            </footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </setup>
    <body>
        <table id="4">  
            <column id="17"/>
            <column id="18"/>
            <column id="19"/>
            <header>
                <row id="5">
                    <cell id="6">
                        <label id="20">
                            <text-prop name="text">NameTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="7">
                        <label id="21">
                            <text-prop name="text">CityTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="8">
                        <label id="22">
                            <text-prop name="text">AgeTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </header>
            <detail>
                <row id="9">
                    <cell id="10"/>
                    <cell id="11"/>
                    <cell id="12"/>
                </row>
            </detail>
        </table>
    </body>
</report>
```

And I want to make modify/make additions to it by consulting another XML file, this one, that gives me the data I want to put in the first XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<model>
    <layouts>
        <layout ID="001" name="PersonTemplate" format="Table" nFields="3" >
            <fields>
                <field name="NameTitle"/>
                <field name="CityTitle"/>
                <field name="AgeTitle"/>
            </fields>
        </layout>
        <layout ID="002" name="SchoolTemplate" format="Table" nFields="3" >
            <fields>
                <field name="NameTitle"/>
                <field name="LocationTitle"/>
                <field name="MaxCapacityTitle"/>
            </fields>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <reports>
        <report layoutID="001">
            <params>
                <sources>
                    <source name="source1" dbURL="sampledb1.com" user="user1" password="dXNlcjE=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                    <source name="source2" dbURL="sampledb2.com" user="user2" password="dXNlcjI=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                </sources>
                <set name="set1" source="source1" querie="select Name, City, Age from PeopleTable" >
                    <qFields>
                        <qField name="Name" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="City" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="Age" type="integer"/>
                    </qFields>
                </set>
            </params>
        </report>
        <report layoutID="002">
            <params>
                <sources>
                    <source name="source1" dbURL="sampledb1.com" user="user1" password="dXNlcjE=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                </sources>
                <set name="Data Set" dataSource="source1" querie="select Name, Location, MaxCapacity from SchoolsTable" >
                    <qFields>
                        <qField name="Name" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="Location" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="MaxCapacity" type="integer"/>
                    </qFields>
                </set>
            </params>
        </report>
    </reports>
</model>
```

So, I want to produce the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <text-prop name="displayName">PersonTemplate</text-prop>
     <data-sources>
        <data-source extensionID="this.is.a.fixed.value" name="source1">
            <prop name="DriverClass">dbDriver</prop>
            <prop name="databaseURL">sampledb1.com</prop> 
            <prop name="dbUser">user1</prop>
            <encrypted-prop name="dbPassword" encryptionID="base64">dXNlcjE=</encrypted-prop>
        </data-source>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <data-set extensionID="this.is.a.fixed.value" name="set1">
            <list-prop name="columnHints">
                <struct>
                    <prop name="columnName">Name</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">Name</text-prop>
                    <text-prop name="heading">Name</text-prop>
                </struct>
                <struct>
                    <prop name="columnName">City</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">City</text-prop>
                    <text-prop name="heading">City</text-prop>
                </struct>
                <struct>
                    <prop name="columnName">Age</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">Age</text-prop>
                    <text-prop name="heading">Age</text-prop>
                </struct>
            </list-prop>
            <struct name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-prop name="resultSet">
                    <struct>
                        <prop name="position">1</prop>
                        <prop name="name">Name</prop>
                        <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                    </struct>
                    <struct>
                        <prop name="position">2</prop>
                        <prop name="name">City</prop>
                        <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                    </struct>
                    <struct>
                        <prop name="position">3</prop>
                        <prop name="name">Age</prop>
                        <prop name="dataType">integer</prop>
                    </struct>
                </list-prop>
            </struct>
            <prop name="dataSource">source1</prop>
            <list-prop name="resultSet">
                <struct>
                    <prop name="position">1</prop>
                    <prop name="name">Name</prop>
                    <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                </struct>
                <struct>
                    <prop name="position">2</prop>
                    <prop name="name">City</prop>
                    <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                </struct>
                <struct>
                    <prop name="position">3</prop>
                    <prop name="name">AGE</prop>
                    <prop name="dataType">integer</prop>
                </struct>
            </list-prop>
            <xml-prop name="queryText"><![CDATA[select Name, City, Age from PeopleTable]]></xml-prop>
        </data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <setup>
        <simple-master-page name="MasterPage" id="2">
            <footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <prop name="contentType">html</prop>
                    <text-prop name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-prop>
                </text>
            </footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </setup>
    <body>
        <table id="4">
            <prop name="dataSet">set1</prop>
            <list-prop name="boundDataColumns">
                <struct>
                    <prop name="name">Name</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">Name</text-prop>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["Name"]</expression>
                    <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                </struct>
                <struct>
                    <prop name="name">City</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">City</text-prop>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["City"]</expression>
                    <prop name="dataType">string</prop>
                </struct>
                <structure>
                    <prop name="name">Age</prop>
                    <text-prop name="displayName">Age</text-prop>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["Age"]</expression>
                    <prop name="dataType">integer</prop>
                </structure>
            </list-prop>
            <column id="17"/>
            <column id="18"/>
            <column id="19"/>
            <header>
                <row id="5">
                    <cell id="6">
                        <label id="20">
                            <text-prop name="text">NameTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="7">
                        <label id="21">
                            <text-prop name="text">CityTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="8">
                        <label id="22">
                            <text-prop name="text">AgeTitle</text-prop>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </header>
            <detail>
                <row id="9">
                    <cell id="10">
                         <data>
                            <prop name="resultSetColumn">Name</prop>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="11">
                         <data>
                            <prop name="resultSetColumn">City</prop>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="12">
                         <data>
                            <prop name="resultSetColumn">Age</prop>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </detail>
        </table>
    </body>
</report>
```

**Note:** The `encryptionID` and `extensionID` both in data-source and data-set are fix values.

So basically the data comes from set `set1` that uses source `source1`, and it also comes directly from `source1` , so I need to have a way of retrieving the correct data from the second XML file.

As you can see, I have can have many `layout` and `report` elements in the second XML file. So, first I think I need to find the `displayName` property in the first XML file and then find the `layout` element that in which the `name` attribute matches `displayName`. Then, I need to, in the second XML file, by the `ID` attribute in `layout` element, find the `report` element that has that same value in the `layoutID` attribute. From here on I would have found the correct `report` element. Only now I would begin to change/make additions to the first XML file. This part I don't really know how to do. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

I know you can use the `document` function to work with 2 XML files, but I don't really know how,

I really need help guys, thank you!

**EDIT**

I basically want to copy everything in the first XML file (**already done**) and then make additions to it with data stored in the second XML file (the one that starts with the `<model>` element

**UPDATE**

Because I want the output to be an addition to the first input XML file, I started, as @Sojimanatsu recomended, by applying an identity transformation, like this (with @TimC's help on a post for the specific problem of the the special characters ([XML - XSLT - Escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208940/xml-xslt-escape-special-characters)) ):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xmlbirtns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"
                              xpath-default-namespace="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--copy the whole input XML file-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--special treatment for setup/text-prop element-->
   <xsl:template match="report/setup/simple-master-page/footer/text/text-prop">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
             <xsl:text>content</xsl:text>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>

      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**NOTE:** The XSLT code that deals with the setup/text-prop element is optional, because my output XML can have `&lt;value-of&gt;new Date()&lt;/value-of&gt;` instead of `<![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]>`

So now I'm being able to print in the output XML exactly what I have in the first input XML. Now, as @Sojimanatsu said, I want to select specific tags and edit them with new data coming from the sencond input XML file, and I also want to add new tags/elements, like the `data-sources` and `data-sets` elements, but I don't know how to do this. I know I have to use the document() function but how??

**To start, how can I add a new element, `<data-sources>` below the `<report>` element and before the `<setup>` element? (`<data-sources>` and `<setup>` are siblings)**

I tried doing this, adding a new `<xsl:template>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xmlbirtns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"
                              xpath-default-namespace="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--copy the whole input XML file-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--special treatment for setup/text-prop element-->
   <xsl:template match="report/setup/simple-master-page/footer/text/text-prop">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
             <xsl:text>content</xsl:text>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>

      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="report/text-prop">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <dataSources>DATA SOURCE VALUE</dataSources>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm getting this output (the dataSource tag comes in the correct place but with some attributes that I don't know how got there):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
   <text-prop name="displayName">PersonTemplate</text-prop>
   <dataSources xmlns=""
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xmlbirtns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design">DATA SOURCE VALUE</dataSources>
   <setup>
      <simple-master-page name="MasterPage" id="2">
         <footer>
            <text id="3">
               <prop name="contentType">html</prop>
               <text-prop name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-prop>
            </text>
         </footer>
      </simple-master-page>
   </setup>
   <body>
      <table id="4">
         <column id="17"/>
         <column id="18"/>
         <column id="19"/>
         <header>
            <row id="5">
               <cell id="6">
                  <label id="20">
                     <text-prop name="text">NameTitle</text-prop>
                  </label>
               </cell>
               <cell id="7">
                  <label id="21">
                     <text-prop name="text">CityTitle</text-prop>
                  </label>
               </cell>
               <cell id="8">
                  <label id="22">
                     <text-prop name="text">AgeTitle</text-prop>
                  </label>
               </cell>
            </row>
         </header>
         <detail>
            <row id="9">
               <cell id="10"/>
               <cell id="11"/>
               <cell id="12"/>
            </row>
         </detail>
      </table>
   </body>
</report>
```

My real first and second input XML files are considerably bigger but once I have this example working I can produce my real XML output,

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this function basically.

[document() function](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_document.asp)

So the idea of this functions is to be able to select another xml file and based on some xpath iterations, use some values from that xml file, inside your new xml or whatever.

Comment: Yes I think so too, but my problem is in the actual XSLT code to produce the final file

Comment: And also I don't really know how to use the function

Comment: Well, thats a learning curve right ? What XSLT you have been trying so far can you share ? Also please identify the problem clearly. The function you want is document() and there tons of examples online how to use it. I might try to implement if you share your XSLT code.

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to copy the <report> and <text-prop> tags from the first XML file to the result XML file, but I'm not getting it right, I just want to copy the two elements exaclty as they are in the first XML file, and then apply the additions to that. See XSLT Fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwg. Then I need to start consulting the second XML file using de document() function. Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly or not. If you want to copy the first XML file, then check it out the identity template in XSLT. This will give you the whole XML file and then you can select spesific tags and edit them with new content easily.

Comment: Can you show me an example of to "check it out the identity template in XSLT"? I'm not quite sure what that means. But yes that's exactly what I want, I don't wanna "take things out" of the first XML file, I just want to make additions to it.

Comment: CORRECTION of PREVIOUS COMMENT: At the moment I'm just trying to copy the <report> and <text-prop> tags from the first XML file to the result XML file, but I'm not getting it right, I just want to copy the two elements exaclty as they are in the first XML file, and then apply the additions to that, using the data stored in the second XML file using the document() function. See XSLT Fiddle: xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwg.Thanks!!

Comment: I've been able to do the indentity template like you said, but now I have the following problem: I have the following element in the input XML: 
<text-prop name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-prop>  , but when I do the indentity template transformation in the XSLT it returns this:  <text-prop name="content">&lt;value-of&gt;new Date()&lt;/value-of&gt;</text-prop> , meaning that it's replacing the '<' with '&lt;' for example

Comment: Thats normal because it is not a text value. Are you trying to use some functions in there what do you want to do with newDate() ? If it is text simply put " " between the value.

Comment: I'm not trying to use functions and I don't want to do anything with newDate(), I just want to copy it exactly like it is. So I just want to get the output XML exactly like the input XML. I posted a question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208940/xml-xslt-escape-special-characters

Comment: I manage to escape de characters for a simple example as you can see in my other post, but when I try it with the whole input XML it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

In general, to reference elements by a certain value, you can define keys with `xsl:key` and use the `key` function then to find a referenced element. In case of two separate documents, if you want to find a value in a second document, you need to make sure you use the third parameter of the `key` function to pass in the target document.

Additionally, in your case you are dealing with one document with elements in a namespace and the second one with elements in no namespace, that requires using prefixes for the two namespaces in the XSLT document or to make use of `xpath-default-namespace` to ensure you select the right namespace.

And if you want to create new result elements in a certain namespace, like the one of your primary input document, you need to make sure you have result elements in that namespace by declaring `xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"` in the stylesheet.

It is not clear to me whether you only want to select certain data sources or sets or what are the criteria do select only one, the following processes all referenced sources and sets. Additionally, only for data sources I have attempted to add templates that transform the attribute centric secondary input data into the target structure, for the sets you have to implement that yourself, currently the default templates simply copy them.

The stylesheet is (with the secondary XML inline, of course in your real code you can use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <!-- second document inlined for the example,
       use param name="doc2" select="doc('file2.xml')
       instead to load external file -->
  <xsl:param name="doc2" xmlns="">
<model>
    <layouts>
        <layout ID="001" name="PersonTemplate" format="Table" nFields="3" >
            <fields>
                <field name="NameTitle"/>
                <field name="CityTitle"/>
                <field name="AgeTitle"/>
            </fields>
        </layout>
        <layout ID="002" name="SchoolTemplate" format="Table" nFields="3" >
            <fields>
                <field name="NameTitle"/>
                <field name="LocationTitle"/>
                <field name="MaxCapacityTitle"/>
            </fields>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <reports>
        <report layoutID="001">
            <params>
                <sources>
                    <source name="source1" dbURL="sampledb1.com" user="user1" password="dXNlcjE=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                    <source name="source2" dbURL="sampledb2.com" user="user2" password="dXNlcjI=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                </sources>
                <set name="set1" source="source1" querie="select Name, City, Age from PeopleTable" >
                    <qFields>
                        <qField name="Name" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="City" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="Age" type="integer"/>
                    </qFields>
                </set>
            </params>
        </report>
        <report layoutID="002">
            <params>
                <sources>
                    <source name="source1" dbURL="sampledb1.com" user="user1" password="dXNlcjE=" driver="dbDriver"/>
                </sources>
                <set name="Data Set" dataSource="source1" querie="select Name, Location, MaxCapacity from SchoolsTable" >
                    <qFields>
                        <qField name="Name" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="Location" type="string"/>
                        <qField name="MaxCapacity" type="integer"/>
                    </qFields>
                </set>
            </params>
        </report>
    </reports>
</model>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="layout-ref" match="layout" use="@name" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
  <xsl:key name="report-ref" match="report" use="@layoutID" xpath-default-namespace=""/>

  <xsl:template match="report/text-prop[@name = 'displayName']">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:variable name="layout" select="key('layout-ref', ., $doc2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="report" select="key('report-ref', $layout/@ID, $doc2)"/>
      <dataSources>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$report//source" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
      </dataSources>
      <data-sets>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$report//set" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
      </data-sets>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="source" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <data-source extensionID="this.is.a.fixed.value" name="{@name}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @name"/>
      </data-source>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="source/@dbURL" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <prop name="databaseURL">{.}</prop>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="source/@user" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <prop name="dbUser">{.}</prop>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="source/@driver" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <prop name="DriverClass">{.}</prop>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="source/@password" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <encrypted-prop name="dbPassword" encryptionID="base64">{.}</encrypted-prop>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="set" xpath-default-namespace="">
      <data-set extensionID="this.is.a.fixed.value" name="{@name}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, *"/>
      </data-set>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ck.

Comment: Thank you so much for both your example and your explanation, it really helped me! What I want to do is put in the result document all the data sources that are from that template, like you did, and then for data sets as I'm only going to have one for each report/template I always want to put that data set in the result document. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Martin! If I want to add two more <prop> elements below the first <text-report> element how can I have them appear exactly as they are in the first input document? When I added those elements to it, they appear below the <data-sets> element and right before the <setup> element. Here is the updated fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ck/1  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Martin, I'm trying to do the same you did for the <data-sources> element now for the <data-sets>. I'm trying to add a new <prop> element that is child of the <data-set> element. I did it like you did for the <prop> and <encrypted-prop> elements of <data-source>, but I don't know why it is not changing the output (the new <prop> element is not being added to it) . I updated the FIDDLE: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ck/2   Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use StackOverflow for help with particular problems then ask them as separate questions, with samples reduced to a minimum to demonstrate what input you have, which result you want, which code you have tried and which result you get. Don't expect people to solve various complex steps of a large problem by exchanging comments to an answer to a previous question.

Comment: You're right I was actually creating a new question but in the meantime I figured it out, thank you!